# JQuery simulating keypress event on an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field which is dynamically filled with some AJAX, and once it's filled I would like to have JavaScript to automatically press "Enter" (key event 13) on that input inducing another function, which is hidden to me, to trigger.

Would it be possible with jQuery? I have this code right now, which is not working:

`$('#myInputId').focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 13 });`

Do you have any clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think passing an object like this should work? Any source?

Comment: I found that `[...].trigger({...});` on another topic here in StackOverflow. I tried it and didn't worked, so asked again.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can create an  [*event object*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

```
$('#myInputId').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the code you pointed out didn't work. I didn't get your comment though. You mean instead of `'keypress'` I should try to set `'keyCode'` ?

Comment: Works perfectly according to [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/SqSyk/) - tested on Chrome 12, IE9 and FF 3.6

Comment: @Masiar he meant changing to `jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 13})` but please see my test case and let me know if it doesn't work for you. EDIT: it might now work if the `keypress` handler wasn't added with jQuery - is this the case?

Comment: Well you test case is ok, but I don't see the point with my problem. I have the input field automatically filled with AJAX (`document.getElementById('myInputId').value = data.from.AJAX;`), and I would like, after this, to simply simulate an "enter" event to submit to that input what has been retrieved from AJAX. I'm searching a JavaScript line of code to do that.

Comment: @Masiar: What is the problem? Does it not work? How is the other function triggered? Which parameters are checked? Does it listen to the `keypress` event?

Comment: It simply does nothing. My AJAX function fills correctly the input box (I can see it from the browser), but the subsequent call that you posted up there doesn't work. This is my current code: `document.getElementById('myInputId').value = data.from.AJAX; $('#myInputId').focus().trigger(new jQuery.Event("keypress", {which: 13}));` but the latter call doesn't happen (if it would, I would have a visual output which there isn't).

Comment: Well, you have to know how the other handler determines whether the enter key was pressed or not. That's what I meant with changing the parameter. If the other handler examines the `keyCode` property of the event object, then using `which` will not work.

Comment: I just discovered by examining the library I'm using that indeed it uses `keyCode`. I then tried `$('#myInputId').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 13}));`and it worked. Thanks for the support and sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: @Masiar: There is nothing to apologize for. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @Masiar for this one, $('#myInputId').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 13}));  
how do you make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Hi you could try use the change event for when the input area changes :

```
$('#myInputId').change(function(){
    $('#myInputId').focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 13 });


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not working either :(.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

```
    var keyEvent = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    keyEvent.keyCode = 13;
    $("#myInputId").trigger(keyEvent);
```

Answer (score -2):

On Keypress `Enter` :

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in somewhere');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrong Answer. Read title of the question again.