# jQuery simulate keypress on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124692/jquery-simulating-keypress-event-on-an-input-field) but it doesn't work for me.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldu6wwv0/

```
$('input').val('test').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keycode: 13}));

$('input').on('keypress', function(){
    $('p').text("worked");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSFiddle works fine on my browser (Chrome).

Comment: It's fine with me as well. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: That's odd. I'm on chrome as well and it doesn't work -Version 56.
I just tried on Safari, Firefox too.. no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be order of your code. Your code which triggers keypress is defined before the event handler.

This seems to work now. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldu6wwv0/2/))

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(){
    $('p').text("worked");
});

$('input').val('test').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keycode: 13}));
```

UPDATE:
Also Please don't use keycode as it is deprecated ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)) and might not work in some cases. I've personally faced this issue. Use **which** instead.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldu6wwv0/4/)

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(){
    $('p').text("worked");
});

var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
$("input").focus().val('test').trigger(e);
```

Comment: Works now! Thanks